# RaspberryPI shutdown script

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi

So I just recently hooked up my new Rasppi, and I wanted to write a script using shell scripts to easily shut down the board. From a single Google search, I learned that this command:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

Will shutdown the PI from the command line. Now I want to turn that into a script file that I can easily run. Is it as simple as pasting it into a text file and saving it as a shell script? Or am I missing something?

Comment: `sudo poweroff` is a slightly shorter way... You can simply put it in a shell script (add a `#!/bin/sh` as the first line and make it executable with `chmod`)

Comment: I heard this wasn't a good idea because it doesn't actually turnoff the device? I don't remember exactly what was said, but everyone agreed sudo shutdown was the best way.

Comment: `shutdown` is the correct way... It typically works by alerting users and then switching to a different runlevel to reboot, halt or poweroff the system. On Linux, the commands `poweroff`, `halt` and `reboot` will also switch the runlevel if run from a operating runlevel. (The man page actually mentions that it invokes `shutdown`) (On Solaris, they directly halt the OS, poweroff the system or reboot it, without giving tasks a chance to terminate...) (`shutdown` is a good habit, but `init 0`, `init 6`, `init 5`, `reboot`, `halt` or `poweroff` can get the same result depending on the OS)

Comment: It would be interesting to see how all this works on non-`sysvinit` systems, like `systemd` and `upstart`... (`sysvinit` you can relatively easily read a few scripts and exactly follow what is going on) (On RHEL you can look at `/etc/rc`)

Comment: What systems would that apply to? Would it not work for most *nix distros?

Comment: The /etc/rc reading (possibly with a slightly different filename), should work on current RHEL versions, older Fedora versions, probably Debian... It won't work if systemd or upstart (or a BSD-style init system) is used... (Some example where this is relevant is Arch) `poweroff`, `halt` and `reboot` should still function as normal, compatbility is generally kept.. (Read `man poweroff`, `man reboot` and `man halt` on your system) (I'm not familiar with the internals of all of them. They are probably anyway watching for runlevel canges for compatibility...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a shell script for it, but typically, this is the kind of thing we make an `alias` for. Aliases are knicknames for common commands and they usually live in a `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` in your home directory.

You declare aliases for all the commands you will commonly run. For instance, if you want to see colors every time you type `ls`, you should be able to include the following alias in your .bashrc:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

Now every time you type `ls`, it's *as if* you've typed `ls --color=auto`.

So, then you could alias your shutdown command, but the sudo part makes it a bit tricky because sudo will overlook your .bashrc. Thus, you could do something like the following:

```
alias sudo='sudo '
alias turnoff='shutdown -h now'
```

You can call it whatever will be easy to remember. After you have edited your .bashrc file, you will have to `source` the file so the changes are remembered:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

After which, your command should probably be able to be run like so:

```
sudo turnoff
```

We're not saving much for keystrokes here, though, and what if you want to restart instead of halt or you want to shutdown in a few minutes (after it's done updating, for example)?

Alternately, since you asked about shell scripting, you could make a shell script, but when you create shell scripts, you will usually have to do a couple of things:

1. Write your script and include a 'shebang' line at the top: `#!/bin/bash` (This tells your shell what will be used to run the script),
2. `chmod u+x` your script to make it executable, and
3. put it in your ~/bin/ directory (and make sure that directory is in your PATH).

You might also look up common .bashrc files, so you can see the kinds of stuff people often make aliases for (this is one of the first things we usually do when customizing a command-line environment).

For example,I still alias `rm` as `rm -i`, which asks me whenever I tell it to delete something and I only ever do `rm -f` if I'm really really sure I want to get rid of something. There are probably many here who would consider this silly, but I've lazily deleted lots of stuff in the past, and so I don't mind the safeguard.

Comment: Rather just use `alias turnoff='sudo shutdown -h now'`. The alias is expanded by the user's shell, so sudo never sees it...

Comment: I ended up following this tutorial for making a bash file: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=9817